# Dropdown menu без нажатия (hover dropdown)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, dropdown

Я смог сделать dropdown menu с помощью Bootstrap но никак не получается сделать **hover dropdown** (автоматический dropdown без нажатия). Как можно сделать это ? Желательно с помощью Bootstrap

Comment: Приведите код дропдауна пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чего-то стандартного нет. Но есть простые решения:

1. `$('.dropdown').hover()`:

```js
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
  $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Наведите на меня
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. CSS

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Наведи на меня
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

А, вообще, Вам правильно уже ответили - поиск выдает достаточно много результатов по данному вопросу!